# Terraform - Can't install "aws linux ami" using t2.micro instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to install "aws linux ami" ami from North Virginia, using instance type of t2.micro, but I can't find ami for "aws linux ami" of virtualization type of "hvm" (I find only of type pv). Is there no way to install "aws linux ami" of type t2?

I ran the following tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "AKIAJHBBU5KDBVL26TBA"
  secret_key = "E3L4+tuTxQKdf+iD3wbWHg6FsHxB+9169ZT7Q4NL"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2d387344"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

* This is the only ami I find for "aws linux ami" in N. Virginia, but its `"Virtualization type: paravirtual"` so I get the following errors:

```
 aws_instance.example: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Virtualization type 'hvm' is required for instances of type 't2.micro'.
```

Only when I use `t1.micro`, it works.

I'm very new with AWS, am I missing something, or there is really no way to run "aws linux ami" of type t2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the AMI ids using the AWS cli:

```
aws ec2 --profile prof describe-images 
--owners amazon
--filters 
'Name=name,Values=amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.????????-x86_64-gp2' 'Name=state,Values=available'
--output json | jq -r '.Images | sort_by(.CreationDate) | last(.[]).ImageId'
```

This returns:

ami-09def150731bdbcc2

For your use case pass in --region us-east-1 as well.

Comment: Really?! This looks over complicated way to get the image. P.s. I tried to use the ami-09def150731bdbcc2, but I got "the image id does not exist".

Comment: You haven't read what I wrote: "For your use case pass in --region us-east-1 as well." Your image ID is: ami-0de53d8956e8dcf80